# SDWebImage Download Image Completion Block not being called

Tags: ios, swift, image, caching, sdwebimage

So [SDWebImage Download image and store to cache for key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902835/sdwebimage-download-image-and-store-to-cache-for-key) this is exactly what I want to do in my application. I want to store the image in a key and fetch image later. This is my block of code :

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with: URL.init(string: url), options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.highPriority, progress: { (receivedSize:Int,expectedSize:Int,url : URL?) in
  print("progressing here in this block ")
}, completed: ({(image : UIImage, data : Data,error : Error, finished : Bool)  in
  print("reached in the completion block ")

  if finished {
    SDImageCache.shared().store(image, forKey: "d", toDisk: true, completion: nil)
  } else {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    showAlert(viewController: self, title: "", message: error.localizedDescription)
  }           
} as? SDWebImageDownloaderCompletedBlock))
```

However, the completion block is never called.

Comment: print("progressing here in this block ") : this is getting printed ?

Comment: yea it reaches in the progressing block but not in the completion block

Comment: any Solution to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this piece of code :

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(with: NSURL.init(string: individualCellData["cover_image"] as! String ) as URL?, options: .continueInBackground, progress: { (recieved, expected, nil) in
            print(recieved,expected)
        }, completed: { (downloadedImage, data, error, SDImageCacheType, true, imageUrlString) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if downloadedImage != nil{
                    self.yourImageView.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        })
```

And you don't have to cache the image again as SDWebImage is doing it already. To retrieve image from cache just use the same url in this code and it will fetch the image from cache if it is there.

**Updated Code:**

If you want to use your own key then use imageDownloader instead of loadImage :

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with: NSURL.init(string: individualCellData["cover_image"] as! String ) as URL?, options: .continueInBackground, progress: { (recieved, expected, nil) in
                print(recieved,expected)
            }, completed: { (image, data, error, true) in
                print("Completed")
            })
```

After `print("Completed")` if there is no error use your caching code to cache the image with your custom key.

Comment: Don't I have to store it to a key and then retrieve it later? Like for some cases in my application, a certain token is being appended to the url and even though the url of the image remains constant, the token varies everytime. Thus, I just need to update the key in such cases. Any Idea on this?

Comment: Check updated code. There is diff in completion block.

Comment: @DilipTiwari any one of them you can use. But I would suggest first one.

Comment: @SharadChauhan what it will do if i use first because i m using sdwebimage could u explain more to load faster image

Comment: @DilipTiwari Both are same, in first you don't need to cache image manually, SDWebImage will do it for you and key for that cached image will be the URL of that image. But if you want to write your own logic to cache the image with custom key use second.

Comment: In my app there are 200 images and it takes time to load @SharadChauhan and what is "imageUrlString" in first

Comment: @DilipTiwari imageUrlString for what ? Use downloadedImage to display image, this is the downloaded/cached image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176056/discussion-between-dilip-tiwari-and-sharad-chauhan).