# Using web image as MapKit annotation (with image edit before)

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, sdwebimage, mapkitannotation

I want to use web image as annotation on Apple Map. In other parts of my app I'm using SDWebImageSwiftUI, so I'd like to use SDWebImage also here. I know there is a SDWebImage plugin for MapKit, but it doesn't look like I can do some operations on image before displaying it. The effect I want to achieve is very close to the Facebook Messenger app:

[image: Facebook Messenger screenshot]

I store square images of user's in DigitalOcean Space (Amazon S3 compatible bucket), so it has to be loaded from the server. After fetching image I need to make it round and add white background (just like messenger app).

I create annotation view like this:

```swift
class MapUserAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
  static let reuseId = "quickEventUser"
  var photo: String?
  
  override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    if let ann = annotation as? MapQuickEventUserAnnotation {
      self.photo = ann.photo
    }
  }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  override func prepareForDisplay() {
    super.prepareForDisplay()
    image = "???"
    // Here I need to load image and make edit (probably)
  }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```swift
  override func prepareForDisplay() {
    super.prepareForDisplay()
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: photo ?? ""), completed: {_,_,_,_ in })
    image = img.image
  }
```

but it's not working (annotation is not displayed, completed is not called and there is no image load error log)

I know I'm missing something trivial, but I have small experience with MapKit, and I cannot find any source about implementing something similar.

How should I implement it? Is my way of thinking close to correct solution?

Comment: are you really using this in a SwiftUI app?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `UIViewRepresentable` to display `MKMapView`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `prepareForDisplay` method you are trying to use the image downloaded by SDWebImage before it has downloaded as you set `image = img.image` outside of the SDWebImage completion block.

However I don't think you'll be able to get the style you want using the default `image` property of your `MKAnnotationView` so would suggest creating a `UIImageView` styled as you wish and added as a subview of the `MKAnnotationView`.

Note that since you won't be using the default `image` property you'll need to manually set the frame of the `MKAnnotationView`.

Since you normally use `MKAnnotationView` by dequeuing (i.e. it reuses views as you move around the map) you shouldn't update the content based on the annotation provided in the `init` but instead use `didSet` of the `annotation` property as this property will be set to the new annotation when the `MKAnnotationView` is dequeued.

Example implementation:

```
class MapUserAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    static let reuseId = "quickEventUser"
    var photo: String?
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet {
            if let ann = annotation as? MapQuickEventUserAnnotation {
                self.photo = ann.photo
            }
        }
    }

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        addSubview(imageView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForDisplay() {
        super.prepareForDisplay()
        if let photoURL = photo {
            let url = URL(string: photoURL)
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: url)
        } else {
            imageView.image = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I already figured it out, but another way (you still were first here). Didn't know about didSet {} in context of annotations, thanks! Also, is `UIImageView` border inset or not?

Answer (score 0):

## First and short solution

Okay, so after some research I found short and clean solution for this. Problem with `.sd_setImage` completion block not being called I fixed according to this SO post: [SDWebImage download image completion block not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504465/sdwebimage-download-image-completion-block-not-being-called). After this one it was really easy to style annotations - everything what I needed is already included in SDWebImage. My `prepareForDisplay()` function finally looks like this:

```swift
override func prepareForDisplay() {
  super.prepareForDisplay()
  let url = URL(string: photo ?? "")
  SDWebImageManager.shared.loadImage(with: url, options: .scaleDownLargeImages, progress: nil, completed: { resultImage,_,_,_,_,_ in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      let size = 40
      guard let result = resultImage else { return }
      guard let resized = result.sd_resizedImage(with: CGSize(width: size, height: size), scaleMode: .aspectFit) else { return }
      guard let modified = resized.sd_roundedCornerImage(withRadius: CGFloat(size / 2), corners: .allCorners, borderWidth: 5, borderColor: .white) else { return }
      self.image = modified
      }
    })
  }
```

Of course it lacks proper handling of image load/modification errors (it just returns, so we can end up without any annotation), but it's not the case in this question, so I'm not posting it here to keep code clean. But there is another problem. Border rendered with `sd_roundedCornerImage` is inset border, which is not what I want. To address this issue I've created UIImage extension.

## Second solution

UIImage extension:

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
  func transformToMapAnnotation(stroke: CGFloat = 6, color: CGColor = UIColor.white.cgColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: size.width + 2 * stroke, height: size.height + 2 * stroke))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setFillColor(color)

    let outerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width + 2 * stroke, height: self.size.height + 2 * stroke)
    let outerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: outerRect, cornerRadius: (size.height + 2 * stroke) / 2)
    let innerRect = CGRect(x: stroke, y: stroke, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
    let innerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerRect, cornerRadius: size.height / 2)

    outerPath.fill()
    innerPath.addClip()
    self.draw(at: CGPoint(x: stroke, y: stroke))
    
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    return result!
  }
}
```

And now my `prepareForDisplay()` function looks like this:

```swift
override func prepareForDisplay() {
  super.prepareForDisplay()
  let url = URL(string: photo ?? "")
  SDWebImageManager.shared.loadImage(with: url, options: .scaleDownLargeImages, progress: nil, completed: { resultImage,_,_,_,_,_ in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      let size = 30
      guard let result = resultImage else { return }
      guard let resized = result.sd_resizedImage(with: CGSize(width: size, height: size), scaleMode: .aspectFit) else { return }
      let modified = resized.transformToMapAnnotation()
      self.image = modified
    }
  })
}
```